# Select string before space Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am curious how can I select a string before the first space instance in Clickhouse.For instance if the string is

*'Joe Black'*

I want to extract *Joe* from it

Closest thing I found is `regexpExtract()` function in the [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-search-functions), but instead of selecting the first instance of characters I want to select the left handside of the of space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use `splitByChar`, which splits the String into an array using whatever character you want to split by. You want a space:

```
SELECT splitByChar(' ', 'Joe Black')[1]

┌─arrayElement(splitByChar(' ', 'Joe Black'), 1)─┐
│ Joe                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The [1] is the first element in the resulting array

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Functions for Splitting and Merging Strings and Arrays](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/splitting-merging-functions/#splitbywhitespaces-max_substrings) functions:

```sql
SELECT
    'Joe Black' AS s,
    splitByWhitespace(s)[1] AS x

/*
┌─s─────────┬─x───┐
│ Joe Black │ Joe │
└───────────┴─────┘
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    'Joe \t  Black xxx 54 ' AS s,
    regexpExtract(s, '^(\\w+)') AS x
┌─s─────────────────────┬─x───┐
│ Joe     Black xxx 54  │ Joe │
└───────────────────────┴─────┘


SELECT
    ' \t 11 Joe \t  Black xxx 54 ' AS s,
    regexpExtract(s, '^\\s*(\\w+)') AS x
┌─s─────────────────────────────────────┬─x──┐
│            11 Joe       Black xxx 54  │ 11 │
└───────────────────────────────────────┴────┘


SELECT
    'Joe \t  Black xxx 54 ' AS s,
    regexpExtract(s, '\\w[\\s]+(.*)') AS x
┌─s─────────────────────┬─x─────────────┐
│ Joe     Black xxx 54  │ Black xxx 54  │
└───────────────────────┴───────────────┘
```